# How to enable remote debugging for an Eclipse Application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-mars

Im trying to enable remote debugging for an eclipse plugin project, for the purpose of using IntelliJ IDEA as a debugger.

The steps I've taken so far:

1. Launch Eclipse.
2. Run -> Debug Configurations...
3. Create a new "Eclipse Application" (as to launch a local workspace which loads the plugin).
4. Add `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=n` to VM arguments.
5. Press the Debug button.

I get the following error:

> ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   agent library failed to init: jdwp

What steps should I be taking to get IntelliJ IDEA to be able to debug an Eclipse Plugin running in a runtime workspace?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried -Xnoagent ?

Comment: No, care to elaborate?

Comment: Why you want to remote debug it? If you can already start in debug mode from eclipse.

Comment: @PeterKirschner Im printing out code at various breakpoints. IntelliJ is capable of showing the value of variables, next to those variables, at breakpoints. I want those values to be printed out as well. I do not believe this is possible in Eclipse. I want to enable remote debug to be able to do this.

Comment: [example](http://imgur.com/6P2S2LW)

Comment: You could use watches for the expressions/variables, but it is not as beautiful as in IntelliJ. But debugging with watches might help you.

Comment: Hovering with the mouse over a variable occurence will also show its current value - again not as comfortable as in IntelliJ.

Comment: What makes you think that remote debugging will give you something that 'local' debugging does not? In the end it is the same debuuger infrastructure at work.

Comment: @Pétur code change on the fly requires you to have the debug connection open to Eclipse. If it is open to Eclipse, you cannot open it to IntelliJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Run -> Debug Configurations...
> - Add -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport= dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=n to VM arguments.

This is redundant. Using a *debug* configuration already starts the application with the eclipse debugger attached to the process. Start it as a *run configuration* instead if you want to enable debugging through a server socket.

You can then create an additional "remote java application" debug configuration to attach to that socket.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you NOT try to launch the Eclipse app from within Eclipse.

- Export the app to be a stand alone eclipse application.
- Modify the eclipse.ini file and add the necessary debug parameters to the '-vmargs' entry.
- Launch the stand alone app as you normally would.
- Attach the development Eclipse instance to the test app as you would normally do for a remote debug.

Comment: This is not what I need; a suggested workaround does not answer my question. I need it to run from eclipse, as to be able to make code changes on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat Configuration:->
By default remote debug happens at 8000 port.If you want to change this then go to catalina.bat file and update this line
set JPDA_ADDRESS=localhost:8000 to desired port no.
And you can also set this  property in setenv.bat file. Generally this file is not there in tomcat so just create one batch file with name
setenv and write this line set JPDA_ADDRESS=localhost:8000.

Now go to bin directory then open command promt and write "catalina jpda start". It will make the tomcat run in debug mode. You can verify it
by seeing something like this "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000"

1)Eclipse

Go to run->debug configuration->Remote Java Application->Click on new Launch configuration
And then fill the detials like project ,port(Give same port no as you have configured in tomcat), host(If you are using local you can give
local then apply and debug
I am using eclipse 2020.09 .

[Eclipse remote debug img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX5q4.png)

2)Intellij Idea:

Go to Add configuration->click on +->and select remote jvm debug->Then give the same port no  and name(any name) then apply.

[Intellij Idea Remote Debug img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9nmE.png)